# CSS selectors, last and first on row, floating elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a fluid layout and I want to set a `margin: 5px;` on all cards, except the first card which will have `margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;` and the last card on row will have `margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;`.

The problem is that the container of these cards is fluid so I will never know which card will be first and last on a row.

Is there a solution for this?

I was trying something like this (but it is not working):

```css
&:nth-child(5n-1):not(:first-child) {
    background: #eee;
}
```

I don't want to use anything but CSS.

Comment: Add some code or image what you want.

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle with an example please?

Comment: you need to use media queries based on which you need to set no. of block's

Comment: I have media queries but the container is 100%

Comment: share your code what you have tried

Comment: if it is fluid, then the only way to do this would be to have media queries for each break point when a container will be wrapped onto the next line.  Please take a tour of the help centre and see how to ask a good question#

Comment: You can create a different declaration for &:first-child and &:last-child selectors and overwrite the properties of &:nth-child(5n-1)

Comment: Why not just add a negative margin to the parent and forget about the cards? `.row { margin: 0 -5px }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could think about this in a different way. Forget about the cards. Add a negative margin to the parent element. This is how bootstrap rows / columns work and is a good solution as it means that the number of elements on a row is irrelevant.

```
.row {
  margin: 0 -5px;
}
```

Example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container:after,
.row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 -5px;
}

.card {
  background: #FFF;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      Card
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```